# video setTimeout AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, webcam, settimeout

I want to make a experience with the webcam, so I'm trying to setTimeout to the addChild(video) to make the video appears after 5-7seconds that user accept sharing his webcam
here's my code:

```
 import flash.media.Camera;
  import flash.media.Video;

var camara:Camera;
var video:Video;
camara = Camera.getCamera();


camara.setMode(980,640,10);

function webcam():void
{

    if (camara != null)
    {
        video = new Video(980,640);
        video.attachCamera(camara);
    }
    addChild(video);

}
setTimeout(webcam, 5000);
```

but what it does is, after 5 seconds the permission to sharing the webcam appears, but what I need is the video to show after 5seconds of having accepting the permission...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently the act of doing `video.attachCamera(camera)` that makes that privacy dialog appear. So do that before you call `setTimeout()` ... then in your `webcam()` function that gets executed via `setTimeout()`, all that is left to do add the video object with `addChild()` to make it visible:

```
var camara:Camera;
var video:Video;
camara = Camera.getCamera();
if (camara != null)
{
    camara.setMode(980,640,10);
    video = new Video(980,640);
    video.attachCamera(camara);
}

function webcam():void
{
    if (video)
        addChild(video);
}

setTimeout(webcam, 5000);
```